# Web checkbox not providing value to function

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, web, components

I've got a weird issue that I can't seem to figure out. I created a web component for a commercial application I have running on a server. If I change the `cbxGramEnabled.Checked` to `True` or `False` the function runs OK and makes the change. However, if I leave the `cbxGramEnabled.Checked` the function doesn't update the DB.

The code that runs the component looks like this:

```
private void WriteToSQL( )
{
    WriteEnableGram( _pkKey, cbxGramEnabled.Checked);
}
```

The `cbxGramEnabled.Checked` is a `CheckBox` on my custom component for the web app.

```
private void WriteEnableGram( int nPKkey, bool bChecked)
{
    string szQuery = string.empty;

    if (bChecked == true)
        szQuery = "UPDATE dbo.CustomKeyAttr SET EnableGram = 1 WHERE pkCustomKeyAttr = " + nPKkey.ToString() + ";";
    else
        szQuery = "UPDATE dbo.CustomKeyAttr SET EnableGram = 0 WHERE pkCustomKeyAttr = " + nPKkey.ToString() + ";";


    try
    {
        string szConString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MetricDB;User ID=webuser;Password=mypass;"; 
        using (var Conn = new SqlConnection(szConString))
        {
            Conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand dbQuery = new SqlCommand(szQuery, Conn))
            {
                dbQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        cbxEnableGram.Text = szQuery; // at least display what the query is somewhere on the page....
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What calls `WriteToSQL`?  It might have something to do with code elsewhere.

Comment: The WritetoSQL code definitely runs.  If I change the cbxGramEnabled.Checked in teh function call to true or false it works a-ok.

Comment: What is the value when you inspect it when you place a breakpoint? Must be `null`, right? Also is any SqlException or Exception thrown? I don't know what happens when you try to run an empty query. Finally, what is the code for the view, where the checkbox is actually placed?

Comment: I dont have access to the code running the form so I can't cut and paste that code; sorry.  This is a custom component in that web application.  I know there's no exceptions, the update function works great when I dump in true or false when calling the function.  I'm betting the checkbox control is null even though I have a check in the box before submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's assume the following is true:

> A boolean value can be `true`; `false` or `null` (unassigned).

The `checked` property of the checkbox can have those values.
Let's also assume that

> If `cbxGramEnabled` contains a reference to a `Checkbox` instance at runtime on that line of code, the value of `checked` can **never** be `null` unless there is some weird bug in its framework implementation. I'm assuming this is a .NET checkbox? Explanation: a reference exists only when the constructor of that object has finished running, and having set all the properties to a default value that is different from `null`.

Since, if the value of the `checked` property would be either `true` or `false`, the code would execute normally, as proven by your attempt with literal true/false values, **we are sure that the actual value is `null`**. Statement 2 proves that **`cbxGramEnabled` does not contain an object reference at that point in your code.**

Essentially, the variable `cbxGramEnabled` has no real value, it contains a `null` reference. The cause for that is that your code is executed before this checkbox has been created.

Typically in a web app, this happens when your page is still loading (creating the components) and your code is executing before the page has completely loaded. This may well be happening between round-trips to the server!! I'm fairly sure that is where your problem is....

Comment: I get what you are saying and I think you are on the right track.  However, the form is generated with the checkbox (and is rendered by the SQL DB ok based on the value in my SQL table).  I select the check box and submit the form and then this is when the problem is happening so its only on update of the form.  From my coldfusion days, this form should already be generated before I select the checkbox.  The checkbox is in a custom component for a web app on my server.  Is there anything special I need to do to reference the checkbox control in this manner?

Comment: @NeonBlue when you do a postback to the server, I think what you actually post back to the server (with a http post) should still contain references to all the controls in that page. Somehow, that is not the case with your situation. I think you should provide more information about the real technologies you use, for example is this ASP or somethng?... For now, I'm fairly sure the problem is **not** between the server and the client when the page is served, but between the client and the server whenever you get your "response" (that is, the second request that should be a http post).

Comment: I'm not sure what the original author used; sorry.  All I know is he provided a method to load a .dll with a control.

Comment: @NeonBlue So the control you are using comes from that dll right? But where does `cbxGramEnabled` get its value from? How dos **your** code "know" (compile) that `cbxGramEnabled` is a checkbox, and has a checked property? If you say you don't have access to the form code at all...

Comment: I've got the ascx file:  
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EnableGramControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="EnableGram.EnableGramControl" %>
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbxEnableGram" runat="server" Text="Enable Gram" 
    Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" />

&nbsp;

Comment: @NeonBlue I now added the ASP.NET tag since it's relevant. Alas I cannot help you further for as far as I know, references to your page components always exist within ASP.NET when doing postbacks. **Except** when your (new) page is already loading/reloading... If this was some event handler (like click on a button), this problem would not exist. I need to know **when** exactly that method is called, in the page's lifecycle...